# .Net Core 3.1 Controller result ignore certain properties if null and not requested

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Lets say we have a data structure like this:

```cs
public class Foo 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public Bar Bar {get; set;}
}
public class Bar
{
  public string Data {get; set;}
  public string Format {get; set;}
}
```

Now in controller trough the API the end user can request Bar data but it's not mandatory (lets say its super expensive to retrieve).

if Bar isn't requested I want the result to be like this

```json
{
  "Name": "Test"
}
```

If we were to request also Bar in the result and lets say it is null, I would like to return something like this.

```json
{
  "Name": "Test",
  "Bar": {
     "Data": null,
     "Format": null
  }
}
```

Is this possible in .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: How are you forming your requests?

Comment: I'm using what comes out of the box when you set up a new asp project.

But now I have tried adding a custom filter with the basic serializer:
`SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter()`

Answer (score 0):

1 way is to use custom converter for your `Foo` class. example something like this

```
public class FooJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override Foo Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WriteString("Name", value.Name);
        writer.WritePropertyName("Bar");
        if (value.Bar == null)
        {
            value.Bar = new Bar();

        }
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Bar, options);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

then you can use the custom converter in mvc with these option

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new FooJsonConverter());
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use jtoken , Convert the object into JToken, RemoveEmptyChildren function will recursive called to find out empty properties and only load properties with value in jobject [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=awRPMR#code-editor)

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please also include an explanation of how to use jtoken to achieve OPs requirements.